# how to make md-toolbar as responsive

Tags: angularjs

i am using a md-toolbar for my page and it is not adjusting to full window, how to make it responsive(media queries ) in desktop as well as mobiles ?

**index.html**

```
<md-toolbar>

<div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <!-- Logo  -->
        <img src="img/logo/1.png">
        <!-- navbar Search -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <div id="right">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group add-on">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Properties" >

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">For Landlords</button>

        <!-- Side Menu -->
        <md-button type="button" class="btn btn-info"  >
         Menu
        </md-button>


    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding flex attributes, as per my copy of the doc example http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/XXYBLK?

Comment: yeah i used <div flex layout = row> even that did not solved my issue.Can anyone help me fixing this ?

Comment: Sure. Could you create a Fiddle, Plunker or CodePen example?

Answer (score 0):

Include a viewport-meta-tag like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.